# Tag wikis for country and citizenship tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It would be nice to have some consistent style for the tag wikis. For example comparing the wiki excerpts

[us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens)

> For questions pertaining to citizens of the United States of America.

[immigration](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration)

> Questions about immigration rules and procedures.

[usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

> Living in the United States of America as an expatriate.

Do we want our tag wiki excerpts to start with "For questions ...", "Questions ...", or nothing? What about having a consistent style for the main body of the wiki?

Within our [xx](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xx) and [xx-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xx-citizens) wikis what links do we want to provide?

Answer (score 7):

## Country-tag wikis

Below is a template for the country tag wikis (both excerpts and main wiki). Please edit, expand, and improve.

**These wikis are now live! If you change something here, please also edit (send an edit request) the relevant tags as well**

**Excerpts:**

> Questions regarding emigrating from, immigrating to and living in the COUNTRY

**Examples:**

- [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

  > Questions regarding emigrating from, immigrating to and living in the United States of America.
- [uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)

  > Questions regarding emigrating from, immigrating to and living in the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.
- [germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany)

  > Questions regarding emigrating from, immigrating to and living in the Federal Republic of Germany.

**Body:**

- Flag: Official flag
- Country: The name of the country in English and in the native language of the country
- Geography: Minor geographical facts.
- Language: Official and de-facto official languages.
- Important treaties: Important international treaties that concern expats, like `EU member state`, `part of Schengen Area`, `eligible in the Visa Waiver Program`
- Currency
- CallingCode
- Timezones
- Link to citizenship tag
- Links to (there should be links in both the official language of the country and in English (if the latter is available))

  - Government's immigration page in English (if present)
  - Government's immigration page in the country's language
  - Link to a directory of embassies in the country (if present)
  - Link to the country's revenue service agency
  - Link to the country's customs agency

**Examples:**

[usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

> ## United States of America
>
> [image: USA Flag]
>
> The United States of America is an English speaking country in
>   Northern America comprising of 50 states. The official currency is
>   the United States Dollar (USD/$), the country calling code is +1.
>   As a large country it uses various time zones spanning from UTC-11 to UTC-4
>
> For questions about being a citizen in the USA see [usa-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa-citizens)
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - Government body responsible for issues pertaining to immigration: [Department of Homeland Security](http://www.uscis.gov/)
> - [List of embassies in the USA](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0004582.html)
> - Government body responsible for taxation: [Internal Revenue Service](http://www.irs.gov/)
> - Government body responsible for customs: [CPB](http://www.cbp.gov/)

[uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)

> ## United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
>
> [image: UK flag]
>
> The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland is an English
>   speaking monarchy in Europe comprising of England, Wales, Scotland,
>   Northern Ireland. It is a member of the European Union (except for the
>   Crown Dependencies: the Isle of Man, Jersey and Guernsey), but not
>   part of the Schengen Area. It is considered as an eligible country in
>   the USA Visa Waiver Progam, but not in the Electronic Diversity Visa
>   Lottery. The official currency is the Pound Sterling (GBP/£), the
>   country calling code is +44. The official timezone is GMT in winter
>   and BST in summer.
>
> For questions about being a citizen in the UK see [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens)
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - Government body responsible for issues pertaining to immigration: [Home Office](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration)
> - [Foreign embassies in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/foreign-embassies-in-the-uk)
> - Government body responsible for taxation and customs: [HM Revenue & Customs](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/)

[germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany)

> ## Federal Republic of Germany
>
> [image: German Flag]
>
> The Federal Republic of Germany (Bundesrepublik Deutschland) is a
>   federal parliamentary republic in western-central Europe.
>   It is a member of the European Union, the Schengen Area and
>   (except for Büsingen am Hochrhein and Heligoland) the EU VAT Area.
>   It is considered as an eligible country in the USA Visa Waiver Progam
>   and the Electronic Diversity Visa Lottery.
>   The official currency is the Euro (EUR/€), the country calling code is +49.
>   The official timezone is CET in winter and CEST in summer.
>
> For questions about being a citizen in Germany see [german-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-citizens)
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - Government body responsible for issues pertaining to immigration: [Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge](http://www.bamf.de/SiteGlobals/Forms/Sprachumschaltung/DE/Sprachumschaltung_Formular.html), [Federal Office for Migration and Refugees](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/migration-node.html)
> - [Diplomatischen Vertretungen in Deutschland](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_diplomatischen_Vertretungen_in_Deutschland)
> - [Foreign embassies in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_in_Germany)
> - Government body responsible for taxation: [Bundeszentralamt für Steuer](http://www.bzst.de/DE/Steuern_International/Steuern_international_node.html), [Federal Central Tax Office](http://www.bzst.de/EN/Home/home_node.html)
> - Government body responsible for customs: [Bundesministerium des Finanzen](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Home/home_node.html), [Federal Ministry of Finance](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Home/home_node.html)

Comment: I like the last part of the country excerpt, but I dislike adding how developed the country is, what religion is usually practiced there, and I also don't know why we need to add statistical data, like GDP, number of immigrants or population data. They are not really that useful, and are usually out of date almost the second you add them.

Comment: I agree with SztupY and would even go further: a fact dump is wholly useless on this site. Unlike [travel.se], where people might travel to a remote country at short notice, anyone who fancies being an expat should already have done some research. Useful information include information about any applicable registration procedure, a link to the immigration office, to a directory of embassies, directories of tax agreements, etc.

Comment: @SztupY your edit was a big improvement. As for the statistical data I agree that it is hard to keep up to data and potentially not useful.

Comment: @StrongBad: thanks, and also thanks for starting the template

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the descriptive pre-ambles for he countries. When I'm trying to choose a tag, I probably already know that Germany is a European country.  I want to know at a glance which tag is appropriate.  The descriptive text belongs in the longer version, not the shorter version, IMO.

Comment: @Flimzy that seems to go against the programming languages tag wikis of SO, the country tag wikis at Travel.SE, and the package tag wikis at TeX.SX.

Comment: @SztupY part of me thinks the last part is actually wrong I think what we what to direct people to xx-citizens for citizen questions. Similarly xx-citizens should direct people to XX for moving to, living in, and leaving questions.

Comment: @StrongBad: edited them

Comment: Rather than 'leaving', should we say 'emigrating from'? It seems a bit more precise and accurate.

Comment: @SztupY I think that we should limit the excerpts to single line or a single sentence.  Otherwise TL;DR; applies

Comment: I am with Flimzy and Karlson, I think even “Germany is a country” is useless, I quite like “Immigrating and living in Germany as an expatriate” or something like that. The tag description should not be about a country but about the questions that go in it. And then the full description can include usage guideline like the reference to “citizens” tags.

Comment: I'd still keep the "If you are a citizen there use 'country-citizens' tag" part at the end.

Comment: This is _really_ nice, and gives us a great tag wiki system with a lot of consistency right from the start. Great job!

Comment: I really like how you all organized your tag wikis so they're so standardized... it almost feels like looking at a real wiki, like Wikipedia, for example.

Answer (score 4):

## Citizenship-tag wikis

Below is a template for the citizenship tag wikis (both excerpts and main wiki). Please edit, expand, and improve.

**Note that these excerpts are now live. If you edit them please also edit the wikis or (if you don't have enough reputation) send edit requests**

**Excerpts:**

> For questions pertaining to citizens of `COUNTRY`.

- `COUNTRY`: Name of the country in English

**Examples:**

- [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens)

  > For questions pertaining to citizens of United States of America.
- [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens)

  > For questions pertaining to citizens of United Kingdom.
- [german-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-citizens)

  > For questions pertaining to citizens of Federated Republic of Germany.

**Body:**

- For aquisition and loss of citizenship please use [citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship)
- For questions about COUNTRY please use [country](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/country)
- Header: Citizens of COUNTRY
- Some details, like:

  - What right citizens have abroad (like being EU citizens, part of VWP, etc.)
  - How to know you are a citizen
  - How to get citizenship
- Links to (there should be links in both the official language of the country and in English (if the latter is available))

  - Government's foreign office page
  - List of embassies of the country

**Examples:**

[us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens)

> For aquisition and loss of citizenship please use [citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship)
>
> For questions about living in the USA see [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)
>
> ## Citizens of the United States of America
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - [USA site for traveling abroad](http://www.state.gov/travel/)
> - [Embassies of the United States](http://www.usembassy.gov/)

[uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens)

> For aquisition and loss of citizenship please use [citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship)
>
> For questions about living in the United Kingdom see [united-kingdom](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)
>
> ## Citizens of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
>
> Citizens of the UK are also EU-citizens, unless they were born in the British Crown Dependencies like the Isle of Man, Jersey or Guernsey.
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - [UK site for traveling abroad](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice)
> - [UK embassies around the world](https://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations)

[german-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-citizens)
>

> For aquisition and loss of citizenship please use [citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship)
>
> For questions about living in Germany see [germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany)
>
> ## Citizens of the Federal Republic of Germany
>
> German citizens are also considered EU citizens.
>
> ## Useful Links
>
> - [Sicherheitshinweise](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/SicherheitshinweiseA-Z-Laenderauswahlseite_node.html)
> - [Deutschen Auslandsverträtungen](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/03-WebseitenAV/Uebersicht_node.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a great idea. Just look on wikipedia: country pages are very standarized, including the table with basic facts and the names of the sections.

The country tag wiki should include the most important about the country, from expat's point of view. It will surely be the population of the country, the percentage of immigrants, the official languages, and the languages spoken so broadly that knowing them would be a great help if you don't know any of the official languages (like Turkish in Germany).

Basic VISA informations, fist steps in given country (for US folks registering your address by local government isn't probably very intuitive). How to apply for job, how to apply for citizenship, banking issues (for example, you can pay money out from ATMs in Germany using VISA/MasterCard, but most shops accept only Germany payment cards).

There are for sure much much more but we don't have to give it all at once. Just move in that direction.

Please pick **one** country tag that will be the **example to follow**. Any edits to that tag will be carefully monitored by community, and format issues can be discussed on Meta. The editors of other wikis will have a great example to follow doing their edits.

Comment: I added a CW answer to maybe be the start of the template. Once we hash it out a little we can move it into the actual tag wikis.